# How to read a specific line with special characters from multiple txt files (50 files) in Java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filereader

Let's say we have 50 txt files with similar format and we want the 2nd line from each txt file. We want only the special character i.e. hash to get removed from the end result.
Mentioning the demo content of only 3 files from the 50 files...

**Note:** I have special character hash in the files, which I can't mention here. Therefore, mentioning **hash** txt here.

**1.txt**

hash

hash How to run JavaScript

hash

answer of the question here...can be any number of lines

**2.txt**

hash

hash How to install EclipseIDE on Windows 10

hash

answer of the question here...can be any number of lines

**3.txt**

hash

hash NetBeans - How to increase the font size of editor, output and menu

hash

answer of the question here...can be any number of lines

**The output I want**

How to run JavaScript

How to install EclipseIDE on Windows 10

NetBeans - How to increase the font size of editor, output and menu

The code I have tried...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{  
        File[] files = {new File("1.txt"), new File("2.txt")};
        // Fetching all the files
        for (File file : files) {
            if(file.isFile()) {
                BufferedReader inputStream = null;
                String line;
                try {
                    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    while ((myline = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(myline);
                    }
                }catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't got your real problem but you can verify the word with `if( myline.contains("hash") )  , if( myline.endsWith("hash)) , if( myline.startsWith("hash))` or many other mehods and pattern on string to check and you can replace the line before printing `myline.replace("hash","")`

Comment: Well, `readLine` gives you one line. So can read the first line, throw it away and then the second one (checking that both are not null).
Then you have the string with the second line and you can remove the hash. If that hash has a fixed length, just use `String.substring(int)`. Otherwise you might have to use a regular expression, depending on how complicated the pattern of "hash" is.

Answer (score 0):

To read the second line of each file:

```
String hash = "...";

for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        try (BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

            // Skip first line.
            reader.readLine();

            // Read second line.
            String line = reader.readLine();

            // Remove hash from start of line
            line = line.substring(hash.length());

            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new Path class can contain more than only a File, for instance a file inside a zip, or some file in the web.

The class Files has many nice utilities.

```
    Path[] files = {Paths.get("1.txt"), Paths.get("2.txt")};
    for (Path file : files) {
        try (Stream<String> in = Files.lines(Charset.defaultCharset())) {
            in.skip(1) // Skip first line.
              .forEach(line -> System.out.println(line.replace("hash", ""));
        }
    }
```

try-with-resources closes in every case, here `in`.

The Stream delivers all lines.

Answer (score -2):

The following code will work.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Splitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File[] files = {new File("1.txt"), new File("2.txt")};
        // Fetching all the files
        for (File file : files) {
            if(file.isFile()) {
                BufferedReader inputStream = null;
                String line;
                try {
                    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        line = line.replaceAll("@", "");
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

`line = line.replaceAll("@", "");` - replace `@` with the special character in your actual file.

Comment: From the first sentence of the question: “we want the 2nd line from each txt file.”

Comment: the second line from each file is: How to run JavaScript, How to install EclipseIDE on Windows 10, and NetBeans - How to increase the font size of editor, output and menu.

OP mentioned that the first and third lines have a special character (replaced by hash). the second line also contains a special character.

Comment: @Asif Yes, the second line also contains a special character. But, I only want the 2nd line from each text file. Also, I want to add 50+ txt files, which is in the same directory. Obviously, I won't be mentioning all the file names in the code. I want to pass the complete directory as well. Also, your code isn't displaying me only the 2nd line.

Comment: @Aman - thanks for the clarification! apologies for the misdirected answer.